# month name not working by using format function in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have used the following to get the stating day of the month

```
multiemp[Day] - WEEKDAY(multiemp[Day],2)
```

For example if my date us 22 May 2018, after using the above query, got the expected out put.i.e., 20 May 2018

Now I tried to get the month name by using the above query and format function

```
format(month(multiemp[Day] - WEEKDAY(multiemp[Day],2)),"mmm")
```

results were not expected, instead of may January is getting populated.

when verify with the following month function expected results arrived .i.e, 5

```
month(multiemp[Day] - WEEKDAY(multiemp[Day],2)
```

but only issue in changing the month number to month name

Please find below:

[image]

formulas used

```
weekstartday = multiemp[Day] - WEEKDAY(multiemp[Day],2)
weekstartday_month = month(multiemp[weekstartday])
Month_name = format(multiemp[weekstartday_month],"mmm")
another_ans = format(dateadd(multiemp[Day],-weekday(multiemp[Day],2),day),"mmm")
another_answer_date = dateadd(multiemp[Day],-weekday(multiemp[Day],2),day)
```

**EDIT: Day 2**
Modified the datatype of the column to date time/timezone.

[image]

after refresh the data didn't change

[image]

**Found out the solution**

Solution 1:

```
mnname = format(multiemp[weekstartday].[Date],"mmm")
```

Solution 2:

```
Month_name = format(date(YEAR(multiemp[weekstartday]),MONTH(multiemp[weekstartday]),day(multiemp[weekstartday])),"mmm")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If is the case you needed urgently you can use `switch(...)` to get the month name. But the right thing is to find out the reason why `format(...)` is not working as expected in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the column instead of repeating the column DAX statement.

```
Column = FORMAT(*nameOfYourStartOfWeekColumn*,"mmm")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you...I have tried as suggested..but still i got the same issue

Comment: @Smart003 I've replicated your code and this works for me. Can you edit your question with a picture of the issue again and show me the code you have used to replicate the issue?

Comment: Change: Month_name = format(multiemp[weekstartday_month],"mmm") TO Month_name = format(multiemp[weekstartday],"mmm")

Comment: Also format your 'Day' column to DateTime dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

Because `FORMAT(...,"MMM")` or `FORMAT(...,"MMMM")` takes as an argument a `date` types and non `numeric` types, try this

```
format(dateadd(multiemp[Day],-weekday(multiemp[Day],2),day),"MMM")
```

If you want the starting day of the week as monday, then,

```
format(dateadd(multiemp[Day],-weekday(multiemp[Day],3),day),"MMM")
```

**EDIT**

Verify that date column is `date` or `date\time` type.

[image: Date_data_type]

Comment: Thank you, i have tried the solution but blanks were getting displayed when i execute the following one `dateadd(multiemp[Day],-weekday(multiemp[Day],2),day)` instead of dates

Comment: @Smart003 Try with `format(multiemp[Day] - WEEKDAY(multiemp[Day],2),"mmm")`.

Comment: @Smart003 can you give an example where blanks are returned? Thanks!

Comment: please see the last two columns `another_ans`  and `another_answer_date `

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
mnname = format(multiemp[weekstartday].[Date],"mmm")
```

Solution 2:

```
Month_name = format(date(YEAR(multiemp[weekstartday]),MONTH(multiemp[weekstartday]),day(multiemp[weekstartday])),"mmm")
```